# I want to convert trading view pine script from version 2 to version 4 and also want to add date filter in below given script

Tags: algorithm, trading

this is my strategy code and i want to convert this in version 4 and also want to add date range filter.

```
//@version=2
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
strategy("AO Trading Strategy")
nLengthSlow = input(1, minval=1, title="Length Slow")
nLengthFast = input(6, minval=1, title="Length Fast")
reverse = input(false, title="Trade reverse")
xSMA1_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthFast)
xSMA2_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthSlow)
xSMA1_SMA2 = xSMA1_hl2 - xSMA2_hl2
cClr = xSMA1_SMA2 > xSMA1_SMA2[1] ? blue : red
pos = iff(xSMA1_SMA2 > xSMA1_SMA2[1], 1,
       iff(xSMA1_SMA2 < xSMA1_SMA2[1], -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 
possig = iff(reverse and pos == 1, -1,
          iff(reverse and pos == -1, 1, pos))
if (possig == 1) 
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (possig == -1)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)         
barcolor(possig == -1 ? red: possig == 1 ? green : blue )
plot(xSMA1_SMA2, style=histogram, linewidth=1, color=cClr)
```

Comment: have you tried converting the above scrip to version 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

for converting from version 2 to version 4 , first you have to convert it to version 3.
for converting it into version 3 you will get error for "line 11: Undeclared identifier `pos`;" and "line 15: Undeclared identifier `possig`;", you have to define these variables first (as i have defined them pos=0 and possig=0). then you can easily convert it to version 4 using the inbuilt pine script converter.

for adding date filter , you can take a start time input and a end time input . Define a variable `inDateRange` which returns true only if the bar is in between that two input time.

```
//@version=4
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
strategy("AO Trading Strategy")

i_startTime = input(defval=timestamp('1 Jan 2020 00:00 +0000'), title='Start Time',type=input.time, group='Backtest Date Range')
i_endTime = input(defval=timestamp('30 Sep 2022 00:00 +0000'), title='End Time',type=input.time, group='Backtest Date Range')

inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime
//
nLengthSlow = input(1, minval=1, title="Length Slow")
nLengthFast = input(6, minval=1, title="Length Fast")
reverse = input(false, title="Trade reverse")
xSMA1_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthFast)
xSMA2_hl2 = sma(hl2, nLengthSlow)
xSMA1_SMA2 = xSMA1_hl2 - xSMA2_hl2
cClr = xSMA1_SMA2 > xSMA1_SMA2[1] ? color.blue : color.red
pos = 0
pos := iff(xSMA1_SMA2 > xSMA1_SMA2[1], 1, iff(xSMA1_SMA2 < xSMA1_SMA2[1], -1, nz(pos[1], 0)))
possig = 0
possig := iff(reverse and pos == 1, -1, iff(reverse and pos == -1, 1, pos))
if possig == 1 and inDateRange
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if possig == -1 and inDateRange
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
barcolor(possig == -1 ? color.red : possig == 1 ? color.green : color.blue)
plot(xSMA1_SMA2, style=plot.style_histogram, linewidth=1, color=cClr)
```

Comment: thank you for helping. it worked for me. but i m getting one problem . date format is not correct, it's showing like this - 1577836800000 and 1664496000000 . please solve this problem .

Comment: hi, i have updated the code , added type=input.time , now its showing the correct time format

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. i really thanks you from my depth of heart. you made my day.